# updating all rows after specific record

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table containing an `int` column named "place". The values from the column determine the ordering of rows from the table on a page. It is for a blog like application. I want a query where I can update the 'place' column for all rows, including the current row, and all rows after the same.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please share with us the table schema as well as sample data..:)

Comment: Well.. if `place` defines order, can't you just use `update table set ... where place >= nominated_value` ??

Comment: `query where I can update 'place' for all rows including and after a row with a nominated 'place' value.` -- can you explain this alittle further.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was fairly clear and simple.  Lets say the table is called 'topic'.  topic has a columns named 'topic_pk' and 'place' (it actually has others, but that info isn't relevant). Now I have a page that creates a new record in topic and inserts an interger into the int column 'place' as part of the insert query.  Now before doing the insert of the new record, I need to run an update that upadtes all records in table 'topic' incrementing by 1 the value in column 'place', but only those records after a record with a specified value for field 'place'

Comment: There is no such thing as "after" in SQL. Tables are just big bags of rows; there is no inherent order to them.

Comment: OK, I would be using >= then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update topic set place = place + 1 where place >= 5
```

Comment: what do you mean 'loop through the update' ? You needed a query that increments all place columns for all rows that have a place greater than or equal to a certain number value. There it is.

Comment: just replace 5 with your number